# Custom Korean font

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to create pdf file.
My customer require using 윤고딕130.TTF, a Korean font which can be downloaded from http://cfile25.uf.tistory.com/attach/206485364D22ED47180F4A.
Problem is Korean text is not displayed when I use that font.
Is that iTextSharp doesn't support this kind of custom font or I'm missing something?

My code is as following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    try
    {
        iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("itextasiancmaps"));
        iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian"));
        string fontPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Font\\윤고딕130.TTF";

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("example.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        document.Add(new Paragraph(@"안녕하세요", new Font(bf, 16)));
    }
    catch { throw; }
    finally
    {
        if (document != null && document.IsOpen()) document.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I believe the `iTextAsian.dll` is related to CJK fonts from Adobe. Since you are using a custom font you shouldn't need those. Otherwise, I tried your code with `malgun.ttf` and it is properly showing Korean glyphs so I'm lead to believe there might be an issue with your specific font.

Comment: Are you sure that this font supports "안녕하세요" glyphs? I have tried Arial Unicode font for the same glyphs and they are shown fine.

Comment: I don't know. But the text can be displayed normally using 윤고딕330.TTF, a similar font to 윤고딕130.TTF. So we suggest my customer using 윤고딕330.TTF font instead.

Comment: Korean text can be displayed in MS Word using 윤고딕130.TTF font, so I think it support "안녕하세요" glyphs. It seems that this font's encoding is "KSCpc-EUC-H", but iTextSharp doesn't recognize "KSCpc-EUC-H" encoding